# Uniform page load

Tags: javascript, html, css, performance, animation

I have two problems:

1. Animation issue(moving while scrolling):

   My HTML:

   ```
   <body>
       <header class="stable">
           <div id="object">
                   <img src="img/object.png">
           </div>
       </header>
   </body>
   ```

   My CSS:

   ```
   #object{
       position: absolute;
       left: 0;
       right: 0;
       margin:auto;
       bottom: 0%;
       width: 45.9%;
       height: auto;
       animation: animation 1s ease-out;
       z-index: 99;
   }

   @keyframes animation{
       from{
           left: -200%;
       }
   }
   ```

   My JS:

   ```
   var object = document.querySelector('#object');
   window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {

       var s = $(document).scrollTop();
       var percent_from_top = s/this.innerHeight;        

       if(0 <= percent_from_top <= 1){
          object.style.left = 150*(percent_from_top)+'%';
          object.style.transition = "0.75s linear";
       }
     });
   ```
2. Problem with strip:

   My HTML:

   ```
   <section id="first_section">
       <div class="strip"></div>
   </section>
   ```

   My CSS:

   ```
   #first_section > .strip{
       left: 0%;
       right:0;
       margin: auto;
       margin-top:-30%;
       width: 40%;
       height: 130%;
       transform: rotate(70deg);
       background: rgba(0,0,0, 0.9);
    }
   ```

It all works...
but it doesn't seem effective enough, because

1. it slows down, and
2. it partially appears

I tried to use clip-path for example, but it works the same way.
Is there a way to create a page more "evenly"?